# How to use Paramiko with python 3.6 and windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, windows-10, paramiko

I'm trying to import paramiko so I can ssh to machines from my windows 10 machine using a python program. However I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "population_script.py", line 5, in <module>
    import paramiko
  File "C:\Users\bnbih\Envs\crossover_env\lib\site-packages\paramiko\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "C:\Users\bnbih\Envs\crossover_env\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 57, in <module>
    from paramiko.ed25519key import Ed25519Key
  File "C:\Users\bnbih\Envs\crossover_env\lib\site-packages\paramiko\ed25519key.py", line 17, in <module>
    import bcrypt
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\bcrypt\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from bcrypt import _bcrypt
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried : `pip install bcrypt` and `pip install --upgrade bcrypt`

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the pip version, and install it with conda? And then try it again in a activated environment. I remember having a similar error when some %PATH% settings were not ok.

Comment: You say Python 3.6, but the backtrace says Python 2.7...

Comment: @RolandSmith running python --version outputs: Python 3.6.0

Comment: @Seio OK. But normally Python 3.6 would not install itself in `C:\Python27`.  Note that according to [PEP397](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) invoking `python.exe` with a script can launch it with Python 2 *or* Python 3, depending on the contents of the file!

Comment: i installed fresh version of python and it all works now. thnx.@RolandSmith